# How to handle database queries in Electron app (with react-redux)?

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, redux, electron, knex.js

I'm building an Electron app using React and Redux that connects to an Sqlite database. I am using knexjs for querying the database.

Currently in my app, I'm using IPC for communicating between renderer process and main process.

```
// actions.js

export const fetchDecks = () => async (dispatch,getState) => {
    ipcRenderer.send('DECKS_REQ')
    ipcRenderer.on('DECKS_REP', (e,decks)=> {                           
        dispatch({type: FETCH_DECKS, payload: decks})
    })
}
```

```
// main.js

ipcMain.on('DECKS_REQ', (e) => {
    knex.select().from('decks').then((response) => {
        e.sender.send('DECKS_REP', response)        
    })        
})
```

Is it a good practice to send a request for each request? 
How should I structure database access in main process?

Answer (score 1):

beyond decoupling the ipc bits from your thunk function, i feel your approach is sound. see if you can 'electron.remote' import your objects into the renderer side since it will make debugging much easier.